# CREATE EVENT to run daily at specified time in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I'm attempting to use the CREATE EVENT syntax in mysql to automatically run a daily table update and in testing, I'm unable to get the syntax to work. It does appear under SHOW EVENTS, but isn't updating the table. 
This is confirmed by checking the create_time in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.

I have read the documentation on the mysql website, as well as countless examples and believe my script should run without fault, but unfortunately, this is not the case.

I have attached my script below for reference:

```
        CREATE EVENT update_customer_segmentation
    ON SCHEDULE 
        EVERY 1 DAY
        STARTS '2017-11-22 06:10:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
    DO 

drop table if exists db_qty;

create table db_qty
select cpf.entity_id as product_id,
    cpf.db_sku,
    cpf.sku,
    cpf.name,
    cpev.value as db_qty

from catalog_product_flat_1 cpf

join catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev
    on cpev.entity_id = cpf.entity_id
where attribute_id = 225;

create index index1 on db_qty (product_id);

-- tx_rank

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tx_rank; SET @cid =''; SET @rn1 =1; SET @del ='';
CREATE TABLE tx_rank
SELECT 
 entity_id,
 created_at,
 customer_id,
 tx_rank
FROM
(
SELECT 
            entity_id,
    created_at,
    customer_id,
 @rn1 := IF(@cid=customer_id, IF(@del=entity_id, @rn1, @rn1+1),1) AS tx_rank,
 @cid := customer_id,
 @del := entity_id
FROM
 (
SELECT 

            sfo.entity_id,
    sfoi.created_at,
    sfo.customer_id
FROM sales_flat_order sfo, sales_flat_order_item sfoi
WHERE sfo.entity_id = sfoi.order_id and customer_id is not null 
GROUP BY customer_id, entity_id
ORDER BY customer_id, created_at ASC 
) A
) B;
CREATE INDEX idx ON tx_rank (customer_id);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON tx_rank (entity_id);

-- sfoi_lite

drop table if exists sfoi_lite;

create table sfoi_lite

select i.item_id, 
    i.order_id, 
    t.tx_rank,
    case when tx_rank = 1 then 1 else 0 end as first_tx,
    i.parent_item_id,
    s.customer_id,
    case when s.customer_id in 
        (161285, 511959, 494475, 295576, 295572, 451501, 64) 
        then 1 else 0 end as wholesale,
    i.created_at, 
    i.updated_at,
    i.product_id, 
    i.product_type, 
    i.sku, 
    i.name, 
    cp.db_sku,
    pc.category,
    pc.supercategory,
    i.row_total,
    cp.cost as item_cost,
    cp.cost * i.qty_shipped as row_cost,
    i.qty_ordered, 
    i.qty_shipped,
    q.db_qty,
    i.qty_ordered * q.db_qty as units_ordered,
    i.price as item_price,
    s.total_paid as order_total,
    i.weight as weight,
    a.delivery_date,
    s.status
from sales_flat_order_item i
    join sales_flat_order s on s.entity_id=i.order_id 
    join aw_deliverydate_delivery a on s.entity_id=a.order_id
    left join tx_rank t on i.order_id = t.entity_id
    left join db_qty q on i.product_id = q.product_id
    left join product_categories pc on i.product_id = pc.product_id
    left join catalog_product_flat_1 cp on i.product_id = cp.entity_id
;

create index order_idx on sfoi_lite (order_id);
create index item_idx on sfoi_lite (item_id);
create index customer_idx on sfoi_lite (customer_id);
create index product_idx on sfoi_lite (product_id);
create index delivery_idx on sfoi_lite (delivery_date);
create index db_sku_idx on sfoi_lite (db_sku);
```

Comment: Show the query you're running.

Comment: Does the bit after the do work when run manually?

Comment: I have added the rest of my script, as requested.
@SEarle1986 yes, the script runs perfectly when executed manually.